# Better way to scrape using VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website, but I'm having some trouble. This is the structure of what I need to take:

[image]

Precisely the 5th line of this table, which have a value of **`10`**. Using the console I can take the desired information with this line of code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")(10).getElementsByClassName("listBranco").item(4).innerText
```

However in VBA, the code is not executed entirely. After some debug I found out that to be successful, I should run only at the `document.getElementsByTagName("table")(10)` point.

If I run with something else from that line used in console, I got the `Run-time error '438' - Object doesn't support this property or method`.

So I was thinking: There is a better way to build this scraping line to use with `InternetExplorer.Appication`?

This is the code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://example.com" 'Cannot pass the real adress because needs login

Do While IE.Busy And IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
     
Range("B2").Value = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(10).getElementsByClassName("listBranco").Item(4).innerText
```

Comment: What version of the MSHTML COM library are you using? Have you considered using the considerably more modern `WebView2` control instead?

Comment: I'm belive I'm using the standard version of Microsoft HTML Object Library which I installed in the Tools > references section. I dont know any others `WebView2` controls. Can you name some of them?

Comment: Try setting `document.getElementsByTagName("table")(10)` to a variable first (e.g. `Dim tableEle As Object: Set tableEle to document.getElementsByTagName("table")(10)` then from the variable, `Range("B2").Value = tableEle.getElementsByClassName("listBranco").Item(4).innerText`

Comment: Always try to get elements by id if possible. Try `IE.document.getElementById("lista").getElementsByClassName("listBranco").item(4).innerText`. It is possible that you miscounted the `table`s on that page.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondWu, but keep occurring error 438 on `Range("b2")...` . Do you know how to inspect an object to see what is inside?

Comment: @Max `Debug.Print`, google how to use Immediate Window in VBA. Try set `IE.document` to a `HTMLDocument` variable first.